# How to find field info in Wordpress postmeta table

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress *postmeta* table has rows with `meta_value` field_RANDOM_STRING. How do I find field info via database?

Sample:

```
field_5617ad2082500
field_56d6bddfc36f7
field_5617b3adf5c19
```

I want to extract info about this field directly via database without going through WordPress / Wordpress Code.

I guess this has something to do with custom field types but I am not sure.

I am migrating the system out of wordpress so wanted help in extracting data.

Comment: As i understand correctly its an ACF fields.
So first of all you need to `SELECT meta_key FROM $wpdb->post_meta WHERE 'meta_value'='field_5617ad2082500'`
Then using `get_post_meta($post_id,'meta_key',true)` you will get info stored in this field.

Comment: Updated title for concise meaning and update formatting and grammar for readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use such code

```
global $wpdb;

$fields = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT meta_key FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value = 'field_58756ba2297d4' LIMIT 1");

$meta_key = ltrim($fields[0]->meta_key,'_');

$meta_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, true);
```

First you get row from database where you will get meta_key for this value, then you should trim if from `_` in the begining of string, because its key for field id, and then you can get actual meta value using prepeared `meta_key` name;